# What does it mean if a public IP address looks like a private IP address?

Tags: internet, proxy, ip, firewall, ip-address

For example, I go to http://whatismyipaddress.com/ and it tells me that my IP address is 192.X.Y.Z. What does this mean? Isn't that a private IP address? How can I find my real public IP address?

EDIT: It may be worth mentioning that I am behind a corporate firewall/proxy.

Comment: It may be the proxy injecting your/its IP into the headers. What is your LAN address? What is the Proxy's address?  If you try https://www.google.ca/search?q=what+is+my+ip or http://www.whatismyip.com/ does it provide the same IP?

Comment: Only 192.168.x.y is a private address.  Anything else that starts with 192 may be a public address.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several ranges of 'private' ip addresses, as defined in [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918). These are:

```
 10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
 172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
 192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

That an IP address starts with 192 doesn't necessarily mean it's a private IP address. For example the ISP Surfnet in The Netherlands assigns IP addresses starting with 192.87, which are perfectly valid Internet addresses (see [RIPE Whois database](https://stat.ripe.net/192.87.1.1#tabId=at-a-glance)).

Only when an IP address is in the ranges above, it's a private IP address and shouldn't be routed onto the internet (and a lot of ISP's block these ranges).

Comment: Of course, IP meaning Internet Protocol, those *are* valid Internet addresses.  And they are routed onto the Internet.  They're just not *public* IP addresses, and are not to be routed onto the *public* Internet.

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard you are totally right my friend. It's too bad this answer went 2,5 years without your comment, I'm sure people will be much better informed now.